# powershell : get-date.adddays incorrect?

Tags: powershell

What I'm trying to do is create a PowerShell script which gets a list of folders in a directory which is filtered by a regular expression screening out folder names with nnnnnnx31 or nnnnnnddd where n = alpha chars for the first 6 characters and the last 3 is either numbers of the static string x31.  Next it screens if the files are 90 days old which will be copied to a different directory.

When i try to run:

```
get-childitem | where {$_.name -match "^\d{6}([a-zA-Z]{3}|x31)$"} | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date.adddays(-90)}
```

I get the error:

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the -lt operator
At line: 1 char: 96
+ get-childitem | where {$_.name -match "^\d{6}([a-zA-Z]{3}|x31)$"} | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt  <<<< get-date.adddays(-90)}
```

I also tried the following and it didn't work:

```
get-childitem | where {$_.name -match "^\d{6}([a-zA-Z]{3}|x31)$"} | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date | foreach-object {$_.adddays(-90)}) }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to do `(get-date).AddDays(-90)`

Answer (score 1):

try this - `get-childitem | where {$_.name -match "^\d{6}([a-zA-Z]{3}|x31)$"} | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays(-90)}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use one where-object instead of two:

```
get-childitem | where {$_.name -match "^\d{6}([a-zA-Z]{3}|x31)$" -AND $_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays(-90)}
```

Comment: upvote for combining the where clauses. terseness and perf improvment.